# Begining with Cordova

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm begining in the world of develop with the latest version of Cordova in Windows (PhoneGap). I understand whow it works (html5,js and css to generate mobile apps) but i don't know how to use the Cordova library, how to implement code, etc

I'm looking for tutorials, firsts steps but all that I found only "How to install this and how to run". Curiosly, all examples for install and run it are based on command lines, but the latest version (for windows) do itself.

Can anybody help me and give me some web sites for start in this way?

Regards,

Comment: AFAK you still need command lines on Windows unless you use Cordova plugin for your IDE (which may be available on other systems).

Comment: you can use Visual Studio Tools 
for Apache Cordova: https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/get-started-first-mobile-app/

Comment: Yes, U'm using Cordova with VS and is the best option for me. The community and the docs is easy to use and the IDE works perfect.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To kick start your first Cordova application development, official documentation is your friend. Check out this link for getting started - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/

Answer (score -1):

This guide shows you how to create a JS/HTML Cordova application and deploy them to various native mobile platforms using the cordova command-line interface (CLI). For detailed reference on Cordova command-line: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html